# Reuse of deleted nodes Ids in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Are Ids of deleted nodes or relationships reused by Neo4j or it just keep incrementing?

If yes, when is it done or how we should do it?

Comment: id's of deleted nodes and relationships are reused after a server restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

id's of deleted nodes are indeed reused. You have nothing to do, you should just not rely on internal id's for external references to your database's resources.

Comment: Not only that, but in the future they may re-shuffle internal records around for performance, meaning the IDs (really just disk indexes) would get shuffled around too.  In the neo4j ruby gem we generate UUIDs automatically so that nodes can be safely referenced.